# join 3 tables where 2 tables are not related

Tags: mysql, vb.net

im not sure if this is even possible. I have 3 tables ;

**TABLE *customer***

-customer_id

-etc...

**TABLE *product***

-product_id
-name
-price
-quantity

-etc...

**TABLE *purchase***

-purchase_id

-customer_id (from "customer" table)

-Date

-product_name ('name' from table "product")

-price  (from "product" table)

-quantity (from "product" table)

-total (from "product" table)

I wanted to merge the "product" table and "customer" table into "purchase" table without any relation between "product" and "customer" table as given above, is it the right way or any better way to do this database. Please Help ...

Comment: Short answer yes:  Each table represents it's own entity.  A customer has to be seutp before a purchase can be made, products have to be in the system before a customer can browse / purchase them.  When a customer agrees to purchase items purchase record is created.  The customer/product tables are considered "MASTER" Data, while the purchase record is "Transactional" data.  You don't want to duplicate the data from teh master data so you record the PK as a FK in the purhcase table.  I would likely store the ID of the product in purchase along with the description if you want history.

Comment: Though "MERGE" isn't the right word.  Purchase is a Junction / associative / transaction table which resolves the many-to-many potential relationship between a customer and a product.  Each table could have surrogate keys (IDs) and Logical keys Customer Name, Product Description, Purchase Date and CustomerID and ProductID  Though likely a purchase should be broken into a header and detail to maintain 3rd+normal form.  or you'll have redundant data and different purchase_IDs when a customer buys more than 1 product at a time.

Comment: hi @xQbert... glad to hear, i do have  product_ID in purchase table. the question is how do i join/combine them into purchase? .

Comment: the product and customer is already in system before purchasing. the FK in purchase table is customer_id and product_id and PK is the purchase_id

Comment: In the purchase table the PK should be your purchase_ID (this is a surrogate key)   The customer_ID and the Product_ID are FK's pointing back to their respective table/key and are part of the logical key with the date of purchase in the purchase table.  To answer your question though: ***how do i join/combine them into purchase*** this is done though the User interface.  When an authenticated user/customer selects the products they want, and you take the information entered and such a record, you create the header get it's id, and then add all the the detail records.

Comment: This could be done in a stored procedure allowing you to have transaction logic if case something fails; or it could be done via multiple calls to the database from the application passing in a header and detail lines.  There are pros/cons to each approach.

Comment: i have already tried JOIN method but it didn't worked out, if i tried multiple calls,is it by doing SELECT method for each table done in the same button function?...cn i do that way?

Comment: Are you trying to select data out of the 3 tables?  if so provide some sample data and expected results.    Be more specific on your question and expected results.`SELECT c.*, I.*, P.*
FROM CUSTOMER C
INNER JOIN PURCHASE P
 on C.Customer_ID = P.Customer_ID
INNER JOIN PRODUCT P
 on P.Customer_ID = I.Product_ID  
-- or maybe on P.Product_Name = I.Product_Name but this doens't seem wise, ID is better.`

Comment: It boils down to this  A customer can have zero to many purchases.  A purchase belongs to one and only one customer.  A purchase must be for one and only one product; but a product could have 0 to many purchases. because you can navigate from customer to purchase to product you don't need nor want customer and product to relate.  What you want is that the combination of a product and customer result in a purchase entity record.

Comment: noted.Thank you for clarifications.